# How to skip the Index

Tags: python

```
#main program
while True:    

        ReadValue = Func03Modbus(1,70,40);#slave,start,number of registers
        x3 = struct.pack('>HH',abs(ReadValue[3]),abs(ReadValue[2])) 
        pressure = struct.unpack('>f', x3)
        print pressure[0]   
        c3 = struct.pack('>HH',abs(ReadValue[5]),abs(ReadValue[4])) 
        purity = struct.unpack('>f', c3)
        print purity[0] 
        hrs = int(ReadValue[30])
        mins= int(ReadValue[31])
        timein =float(str(ReadValue[30])+"."+str(ReadValue[31]))    
        print timein 
        r=requests.get("http://api.thingspeak.com/update api_key=5RMT************&field4="+str(pressure[0])+"&field5="+str(purity[0])+"&field1="+str(ReadValue[i])+"&field2="+str(mins)+"&field3="+str(timein)))
        print str(ReadValue[30])  
        time.sleep(15)
```

While running the above program it stops running with returning following error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "/home/pi/v1.py", line 123,
>   in 
>       x3 = struct.pack('>HH',abs(ReadValue[3]),abs(ReadValue[2])); IndexError: tuple index out of range

I want my program to run continuously even when it returns error. I want to skip the error and to run the program continuously. How can I do that ?

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/errors.html

Comment: I would suggest you try adding `print len(ReadValue)` before the `.pack()`. You can then determine how many elements are returned when it fails.

Answer (score 2):

In theory you could wrap the code in an exception handler like:

```
while True:
    try:
        what you want to do
    except Exception as e:
        print("Something bad happened:", e)
    finally:
        # reset device here
        time.sleep(15)
```

But this seems like a really bad idea if you're interacting with hardware, since you can't be sure what state you're leaving it in. Ideally, you'd want to make sure you're doing a proper reset of the device (or reconnect? depends what you're talking to) on every cycle.

Alternatively, if you want to explicitly verify that the values you get back are available, you can do:

```
ReadValue = Func03Modbus(1,70,40);#slave,start,number of registers
if len(ReadValue) < 32:
    print("Got incomplete result")
    time.sleep(15)
    continue
```

The language reference/tutorial has more information about handling errors here: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/errors.html

Comment: "if len(ReadValue) < 32: " for what the "32" stands for ? whether it denotes bit size?

Comment: @fayaaz The highest value you read is `ReadValue[31]`, so `ReadValue` needs at least 32 elements.

Comment: I am not reading 32 values ...... I am just concatenating the ReadValue[3] and ReadValue[2] and doing some float conversion.

Comment: `ReadValue[31]` means that you're getting the 31st element from that list. You're getting `IndexError` because you're not getting all the expected registers back. In that error, either your `ReadValue[2]` or `ReadValue[3]` is missing. Later on you are accessing 31 - `mins= int(ReadValue[31])`

Answer (score 0):

In order to continue in the event of this kind of error, simply place the part you wish to ignore exceptions in within an appropriate `try: ... except ...`

```
while True:    
    try:
        <body of work>
    except IndexError:
        <you might want to log the error>
        pass
```

In this case, we continue only in the event of `IndexError`.